# Double quotes inside double quotes in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Phoenix this works:

```
    <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
```

I wonder, how does it work with quotes inside quotes, isn't it supposed to throw an exception? In ruby it would and in many other frameworks it would also.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter. It's two different languages. The browser never sees the "innner" quotes, because those are evaluated/executed/replaced at the server, and the ONLY thing the browser sees is the OUTPUT of that code. The quotes never reach the browser.

Conversely, the parsing engine doesn't care whatsoever about the "outside" quotes, because they're not within `<% ... %>` blocks, so they're note "code" quotes, they're just some random characters that it couldn't care less about.

Mixing programming languages like this is all about context: What's evaluating the code, WHERE it's being evaluated, and WHEN it's being evaluated.

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                      handled server-side


<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
             ------- handled client-side------------
```